# Aplicar el callback

Tags: javascript

Cordial saludo, este ejercicio me piden que lo resuelva pero con callbakcs, de modo tradicional con MAPS lo resuelvo pero justo me piden sin eso, al implementar la forma callbacks en la función del prototipo no me da. Alguno me puede guiar para entender la pregunta. Dejo el código que hice.

```
function mapear() {
  // Escribi una funcion mapear en el prototipo del objeto global 'Array'
  // que recibe una funcion callback , que se ejecuta por cada elemento del array
  // mapear los elementos de ese array segun la funcion callback
  // Esta funcion tiene que devolver un array nuevo con los elementos mapeados.
  // NO USAR LA FUNCION MAP DE ARRAYS.
  // ej:
  // var numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  // numeros.mapear(function(numero) {
  //   return numero + 1;
  // }) devuelve [2, 3, 4, 5]

  // Tu código aca:
    

    Array.prototype.mapear = Array.filter(function(array){ for (var i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
       return sort(Array[i]);
    };
     
     
    };





}
```

Comment: ¿Se puede saber la fuente de estos ejercicios? Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Breve explicación: en el fragmento se está recibiendo el callback como parámetro. Internamente en la función se crea una variable temporal (se recomienda usar let/const en lugar de var si el browser es compatible con ES6). Esta variable temporal será un array vacío donde insertar los nuevos valores, una vez ejecutado el callback sobre él.

El siguiente paso es iterar por el array (variables this), y el valor resultado del callback, lo vamos insertando y añadiendo al array temporal.

Una vez finalizada la iteración por los elementos sin usar .map(), se devuelve el array temporal.

Adicionalmente, dos ejemplos más:

- Ejemplo 2: funcionamiento sobre un array vacío; al no existir elementos, el bucle for no se ejecuta y por tanto se devuelve el array temporal (que quedó vacío).
- Ejemplo 3: funcionamiento con un callback distinto: al ejecutar la función sobre un array de cadenas, y debido al operador "+" se realiza la concatenación.

```js
Array.prototype.mapear = function(cb) {
  let newArray = [];
  for(let i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
      const x = cb(this[i]);
      newArray.push(x);
  }
  return newArray;
};

// Tu ejemplo
var numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var result = numeros.mapear((num) => num + 1);
console.log('Result 1: ', result);

// Otros ejemplos
console.log('Result 2: ', [].mapear((num) => num + 1));
console.log('Result 3: ', ['A', 'B'].mapear((num) => num + 10));
```

Espero que sirva. Cualquier duda, en los comentarios.